# Cannot setup a reverse proxy with Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, node.js, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to display my `NodeJS` application when the user type a specific domain. I already pointed the domain on the server, then I've installed `Nginx` and I have created a configuration file into:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf
```

this have the following content:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myapp.it www.myapp.it;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4568;
        }
}
```

I restarted `Nginx` and I executed this command: `nginx -t` but I got:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "myapp.it" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.myapp.it" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

when I visit the domain I get 403 Forbidden, that's because `Letsencrypt` cannot register a certificate for the conflict above. What I did wrong?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and identify where the conflicting `server_name` is coming from. Has your editor left a backup file in the `conf.d` directory perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the site config files in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

To solve your problem, check if you have a default site config in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and delete it. Then, move your myapp.conf file to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and restart nginx.

Comment: You're right! What if I have multiple node js app? Should I create a new conf each time?

Comment: I don't know very much about node js apps. If each of them listens in different ports then you could add multiple locations entries in the site config, each with a different port. You sure can also add a new site config file for each app. It's up to you.